# Sort the string based on conditions using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to sort the string based on the following conditions...

here is the input "100AP12345678"

need output like 100 in one string AP in another and 1234567890 in another..

I did like below

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Numeric>[0-9]+)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)");



        var input=TextBox1.Text;

        var match = numAlpha.Match(TextBox1.Text);

        var Amount = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;

        var Operator = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;

        var index = Operator.Substring(Operator.Length - 1);

        var MobileNum = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(index) + 1);

        var kk = numAlpha.Match(MobileNum).Groups["Alpha"].Value;

        if ((Operator.Length > 2) & ((numAlpha.Match(MobileNum).Groups["Alpha"].Value).Length != 0) || (MobileNum.Length > 10))
        {
            Label1.Text = Amount;
            Label3.Text = "invalid MobileNum";
            Label2.Text = "invalid operator";
        }

        else if (((numAlpha.Match(MobileNum).Groups["Alpha"].Value).Length != 0) & (MobileNum.Length > 10))
        {
            Label1.Text = Amount;
            Label2.Text = Operator;
            Label3.Text = "invalid MobileNum";
        }
        else if (Operator.Length > 2)
        {
            Label1.Text = Amount;
            Label2.Text = "invalid operator";
            Label3.Text = MobileNum;
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = Amount;
            Label2.Text = Operator;
            Label3.Text = MobileNum;
        }
    }
```

first charcaters i.e numbers are rupees and next two are operator and the remaining are mobile number

conditions:

1.amount will have no limitation
2.operator should be two characters
3.mobileNum should not exceed 10

the above code works good

but two limitations
1. when I am passing input starting with alphabets it doesnt work

like ab1001234567890
as I have given regex function as numbers and alphabets
and second limitation is
when i Pass operator like aba its not showing invalid operator as I used Substring..

Everything works good if I pass input like 
100VD9441239494

here two limitations in the code

1.If I pass VD1009441239494 doesnt work n achevie my requirements

2. if i pass reapareted characters in operartor like
   100VDV9441239494 not getting perfect output as I used Substring

Comment: which fields are optional?

Comment: No fileld is Optional filed.....

Comment: 1.amount will have no limitation
2.operator should be two characters
3.mobileNum should not exceed 10 like 10000VD9441239494

Comment: but this `lk109032030002` misses the first part.

Comment: it is working good when i pass the input like 10000VD9441239494   and if i pass like VD1009441239494 it doesnt

Comment: so you want to return false for `VD1009441239494` input?

Comment: Is there anything fixed in your pattern ?

Comment: If I pass VD1009441239494 it shows error like StartIndex cannot be less than zero.

Comment: No fixed Pattern Operator characters should be two and mobile num should not exceed ten characters

Comment: yes exactly @
 
so you want to return false for VD1009441239494 input?

Comment: OK. How do you come to know, if the numbers given in the last is only mobile number or the combination of mobile number and rupees ?

Comment: thats d second thing first need to return false for the input starts with alpha like VD1009441239494 and second thing is everything works good for input 100VD9441239494 and if i pass operator like repeated characters like 100VDV9441239494  var MobileNum = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(index) + 1); doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS u have only one exception as u said u can make use of try n catch blocks and run n test d code works good

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var numAlpha = new Regex(@"^(?<Numeric>[0-9]+)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<mnum>\d+)$");

            var input = TextBox1.Text;

            var match = numAlpha.Match(TextBox1.Text);

            var Amount = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;

            var Operator = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;

                var index = Operator.Substring(Operator.Length - 1);

                var MobileNum = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(index) + 1);


            var kk = numAlpha.Match(MobileNum).Groups["Alpha"].Value;

            if ((Operator.Length > 2) & ((numAlpha.Match(MobileNum).Groups["Alpha"].Value).Length != 0) || (MobileNum.Length > 10))
            {
                Label1.Text = Amount;
                Label3.Text = "invalid MobileNum";
                Label2.Text = "invalid operator";
            }

            else if (((numAlpha.Match(MobileNum).Groups["Alpha"].Value).Length != 0) & (MobileNum.Length > 10))
            {
                Label1.Text = Amount;
                Label2.Text = Operator;
                Label3.Text = "invalid MobileNum";
            }
            else if (Operator.Length > 2)
            {
                Label1.Text = Amount;
                Label2.Text = "invalid operator";
                Label3.Text = MobileNum;
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = Amount;
                Label2.Text = Operator;
                Label3.Text = MobileNum;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Label4.Text = "invalid input";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use anchors.

```
var numAlpha = new Regex(@"^(?<Numeric>[0-9]+)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<mnum>\d+)$");
```

OR

```
var numAlpha = new Regex(@"^(?<Numeric>[0-9]+)(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]{2})(?<mnum>\d{10})$");
```

- `^` Start
- `\d+` One or more digits.
- `[a-zA-Z]+` One or more alphabets.
- `$` End.

Comment: If I replaced that then I cant able to retrive the amount value if i given i/p like lk109032030002..

Comment: means I need to display as wrong i/p after submitt Button

Comment: then got error like  StartIndex cannot be less than zero. at  var index = Operator.Substring(Operator.Length - 1);

Comment: problem is not with the regex.

Comment: @ManoharJonnalagadda you the one said "resolved" then why you unaccept my answer? I'm the one who provides a correct regex at very first.

Answer (score 0):

One more regex which will match your criteria. The `first group` will give you the rupees, second group will give your the operator and third group will give you the mobile number.

```
\b(\d+)([a-zA-Z]{2})(\d{10})\b
```

`\b`            - Start of a word boundary.
`(\d+)`         - Will match digits (rupees).
`([a-zA-Z]{2})` - Will match the 2 character operator.
`(\d{10})`      - Will match the 10 digit telephone number.
`\b`            - End of word boundary.

You can have a [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eE0eA9/1).